What TF2 map is at 1:25:35 of the Blue's Roost weapon deletion video?
At the 1 hour 25 minute 35 second mark of the video "What if we deleted half of TF2's weapons?" by
Blue's Roost, gameplay from a Control Point map set in a small town is shown. What map is this?


It is amazing to me that a 2h video about a game that has been out for 20 years has gotten tens of thousands of views.  Bravo all around.

This is the map cp_overgrown, officially added to the game in the Summer 2024 Update. It was previously a map on tf2maps and on the Steam Workshop.
Here's a screenshot of the map that matches closely with your screengrab from the video; the original is from the wiki.

